# Lottery probability with payout system

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics

Assume we have a lottery which has following payouts `1,2,5,6,9,10,16`. The organizer expects `4%` profit from the lottery. I wrote some PHP code which simulates this but I am not good at probability so I am getting wrong results.
I wrote my PHP code in this question but I'm sure it will not confuse those people who do not know any programming languages.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)/*number of tickets generated*/ {

    $mainrand   =   rand(1,100); //probable outcome for each ticket

    $pay = 0;

    if($mainrand > 96 && $mainrand <=100){

        $pay = 0;

    }
    if($mainrand > 90 && $mainrand <=96){

        $pay = 16;

    }
    if($mainrand > 81 && $mainrand <=90){

        $pay = 10;

    }
    if($mainrand > 72 && $mainrand <=81){

        $pay = 9;

    }
    if($mainrand > 60 && $mainrand <=72){

        $pay = 6;

    }
    if($mainrand > 48 && $mainrand <=60){

        $pay = 5;

    }
    if($mainrand > 24 && $mainrand <=48){

        $pay = 2;

    }
    if($mainrand > 0 && $mainrand <=24){

        $pay = 1;

    }
    $money += $pay;


}


echo $money;
```

I expect the `$money` to be very close to `9600` But it is far away.
The logic in this code was to calculate the probability of getting let's say 16X payout from 96 possible outcomes and so on by reducing each probability from outcomes.
I increase the random generated number to aprox. 480 and everything gets to its places but I want to understand the logic.
 Payouts and profit margin can be changed so it would be wonderful if someone could help me understand the logic (algorithm) that this could be counted.

Comment: Not clear as to the question.  Are you looking for a list of probabilities (one for each payout) such that the expected return on a dollar is 96 cents?

Comment: Yes. For example I want to sell tickets on 100USD  get profit of  4USD and pay 96USD prize money ( some of which could be 16USD, 5USD 1USD ...) in this case I assume the ticket costs 1USD but all these numbers can be change.

Comment: But there are lots of such lists that will work (for example, make the probability of winning $1 96% and all the other probabilities 0).  What other properties do you want?

Comment: Yes You are right. In this case I chose these payouts 1,2,5,6,9,10,16 as an example.

Comment: No, it isn't the payout that's confusing...it's what relation you want between them.  In the answers, I posted a possible solution.  To get it I computed 1/payout for all the payouts and then I scaled these back so that, viewed as probabilities, they gave me the right expected return.  That felt right to me, but it might not be what you had in mind.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you calculated that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26275/discussion-between-lulu-and-yervand-khalapyan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a table of payout probabilities that has the property that the expected return on a dollar is 96 cents, and which scales like 1/payout.  With probability 71% (or so) you win nothing.  Not sure if this is close to what you intend, but perhaps it is a start?

1:  0.137142857

2:  0.068571429

5:  0.027428571

6:  0.022857143

9:  0.015238095

10: 0.013714286

16: 0.008571429

The way I built this list:  I took the 7 possible payouts and computed their reciprocals ($\frac 1k$ for each payout k).  I wanted to use these for my probabilities because the way they decayed felt right to me (I had no scientific reason for preferring this method).  Now I just scaled them to fit.  That is, I noted that $\sum payout*\frac{1}{payout} = 7$ and I wanted it to be .96 so I multiplied by .96 and divided by 7. To summarize, for each payout k we have $$Prob(k)= \frac 1k \frac {.96}{7}$$ That's it!