# Lottery payout with organizer margin.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

Assume we have a lottery with payouts like this 
$(1,2,3,4,5,25,30,100)$
So you buy a ticket and you can win a pot which will multiply your ticket price by the numbers written ahead. 
The organizer expects a margin profit of $4\%$ from all tickets.
What I have done looks like this. 
`(1-0.04)/1*8= 0.12` (this will be the probability of getting a ticket which has a payout of $1$ where $8$ is number of payouts in my payout table)
`(1-0.04)/6*8= 0.02` (this will be the probability of getting a ticket which has a payout of $6$ and so on)
I will add up all probabilities and the remaining probability will be the probability of getting a ticket with no winning. 
I wanted someone to look through it and tell me if everything is correct. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your method it looks like you want the winning probabilities to scale inversely with the payouts (i.e. if $P_i$ is the probability of winning the $i^{th}$ payout and $r_i$ is the value of that payout then you ensured that $P_i \propto \frac1{r_i}$).  You then scaled these so that the expected payout for one person was $0.96$.  This is fine as long as $\sum P_i \leq 1$ (for instance a payout system of $\left(\frac15, 5 \right)$ would not allow this).

In general as long as your winning probabilities satisfy

$$\sum P_i \cdot r_i = 0.96 \cdot b$$

and

$$\sum P_i \leq 1$$

you will achieve the expected profit margin of $0.04$ (here $b$ is the cost of a ticket).  For instance if your payouts were $(2, 3, 5)$ and your ticket price was $1$ then you could select the probabilities $(0.192, 0.096, 0.0576)$ since it gives you

$$
\begin{align}
\sum P_i \cdot r_i &= 0.192 \cdot 2 + 0.096 \cdot 3 + 0.0576 \cdot 5 \\
&= 0.96
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
\sum P_i &= 0.192 + 0.096 + 0.0576 \\
&= 0.3456 \\
&\leq 1.
\end{align}
$$

Likewise you could have chosen $(0.096, 0.096, 0.096)$ or any other probability combination that might satisfy the two requirements above.

The reason behind this is your lottery system follows a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).  If $N$ people enter the lottery and there are $k$ payouts with probabilities $(p_0, p_1, \dots ,p_k)$ (note $p_0$ is the probability that you win nothing) then the multinomial distribution can tell you how likely it is for $x_i$ people to win the $i^{th}$ payout.

Now the multinomial distribution has the nice property that the [expected number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of people to win the $i^{th}$ payout is given by

$$E(X_i) = N \cdot p_i.$$

The value you really care about is the expected total payout.  To arrive at this we first see that

$$Y = \sum_{i=0}^{k}r_i \cdot X_i$$

is the [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) representing the total payout amount (we are just multiplying the payout amounts times the number of people that won those payouts and then summing them all up).  As such the expected total payout is

$$
\begin{align}
E(Y) &= E(\sum_{i=0}^{k}r_i \cdot X_i) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{k}r_i \cdot E(X_i) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{k}r_i \cdot N \cdot p_i \\
&= N\sum_{i=0}^{k}r_i \cdot p_i.
\end{align}
$$

Now you want this value to equal $0.96 \cdot \mbox{(the total income)}$ which is

$$0.96 \cdot \mbox{(the total income)} = 0.96 \cdot N \cdot b.$$

Equating these two values we see that

$$
\begin{align}
N\sum_{i=0}^{k}r_i \cdot p_i &= 0.96 \cdot N \cdot b \\
\sum_{i=0}^{k}r_i \cdot p_i &= 0.96 \cdot b
\end{align}
$$

which is the condition we were looking for.

In reference to your previous question ([Lottery probability with payout system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374929/lottery-probability-with-payout-system)) you will see that the expected total payout is $47100$.  This number comes from the above formula for $E(Y)$ with $N=10000$ and the probabilities and payouts from your PHP code.  Running this code many times and averaging the result will confirm this number.

Comment: Luke thank you for your answer, but can you please explain in an easier way. What you wrote is very complicated and it would be wonderful if you can explain it one more time. thank you.

Comment: @YervandKhalapyan: I edited a few things and added some wikipedia references.  If you need additionally explanation then let me know which piece is confusing to you (i.e. you do not quite understand what the expected value means,  are unsure what a random variable is, etc.) so that I can clarify those points.

Comment: Luke I may annoy you but I still don't understand one thing. Can you please explain how you got probabilities of the example you brought (2,3,5) as by the method you told I couldn't get these numbers (0.192,0.096,0.0576). Thank you.

Comment: Yes that was the same thing I was trying to do but I was not able to get eg. 0.0576

Comment: @YervandKhalapyan Sorry, I didn't finish my original comment and ran out of time. There are many probabilities that could work.  I chose those arbitrarily.  If you want the probabilities to scale inversely with the payouts then you would start with: $(2, 3, 5) \rightarrow (0.500, 0.333, 0.200 )$  Then determine what you would need to scale them by so that the expected payout is 0.96: $x(0.500 \cdot 2 + 0.333 \cdot 3 +0.200 \cdot 5) = 0.96 \rightarrow x = 0.32$  This leaves you with $(0.160, 0.107, 0.064)$ (You should also check that the sum of the probabilities is less than 1)

Comment: Now everything is clear. Thank you very much. I appreciate that.

Comment: @YervandKhalapyan No problem.  Glad I could help.

Comment: The confusion came from this 0.192⋅2+0.096⋅3+0.0576⋅5=0.96(0.768) :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that when you say the organizer expects a profit margin of 4% from all the tickets that the expected value contribution from each ticket size where you win something is equal, otherwise there are many probability distributions that satisfy your requirements. Also presumably there is a probability of not winning anything, otherwise the organizer is guaranteed to lose money with those payoffs.

Then we have if $P_n$ is the probability of payoff $n$ and there are $N$ total positive payoffs that $P_nn = 0.96/N$. Then you get the formula that $P_n = \frac{0.96}{nN}$, which seems to be what you have in your question. Thus, I would say yes, you are correct.